# Access Wireguard inside WSL2 from Windows 10 Host

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wireguard

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on WSL2 on Windows10 wireguard. I am using this wireguard to connect to the server. I am able to ping the server successfully using that wireguard interface wg0 on WSL2. Example: ping -I wg0 <IP @ on Server Side>

I want that specific to the laptop that I am using. What I want is that windows can access the wireguard through the WSL. Basically, want to work around the Wireguard Client Windows Application.

How exactly can I do this ? Make the default gateway of windows to be the IP address of Wireguard interface. But then eventually the packets, will go through the actual network interface (WiFi / Ethernet port ). So, what exactly should I do ?

I have enabled proxyarp and ipv4 forwarding in Linux and Windows, but I cannot ping eth0 (Network interface) to Wireguard interface (wg0) also.

Is there any way to do it? Then I plan make a UI just like wireguard windows application that use sshs commands for WSL2 and Powershell for Windows when the user hits activate this and make the VPN start.

Is there any other way around this ? Like using Docker or Virtual Box or VMware ? I also have to make the UI specific to this setup.

-> VPN works specific to the wg0 interface.

[image]

Comment: "How exactly can I do this?" - Create a route from the laptop to the WSL2 instance.  By default the IP address of the WSL2 won't be static. Have you tried creating that route?

Comment: Hello, I have edited the original question and added a link to the setup here :  
                                                                                
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR7Z9.jpg                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                        I have setup the route from laptop to WSL2. Please let me know any specific questions ? Thank you !!

Comment: Why not use a real Virtual Machine for this task?